# Using Apple Push Notification Service to Push Application Updates

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new to iOS development and I recently came to know about the Apple Push Notification Service.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to push application updates to iPhone/iPad devices using Apple Push Notification Service..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194):

> Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application
>   that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has
>   information for them. The information could be a message, an impending
>   calendar event, or new data on a remote server. When presented by the
>   operating system, local and push notifications look and sound the
>   same. They can display an alert message or they can badge the
>   application icon. They can also play a sound when the alert or badge
>   number is shown.

So no, you can't push application updates. You could send a message telling the user that an update was available, though that would be considered pretty obnoxious by many users.

Comment: Any other technology apart from APNS that would allow application updates to be pushed to iPhone/iPad devices rather than user having to go to App Store and download the updated version..?

Comment: No, the only way to download updates to the app is using the App Store app (or iTunes). Unless you're talking about _content_ rather than the code.

Comment: No I was not talking about the content. What I want to do is to push a newer updated version (i.e. code) of the application to the users who have already downloaded the previous version of the application. Unfortunately, seems Apple doesn't support the capability to do this. Anyway thanks for the information.